# How to swallow mouse input while using Raw Input?

Tags: windows, hook, mouse, raw-input, mouse-hook

**Situation**: I am working on an overlay application that needs to intercept the input headed to another process and block that input if necessary.

**Previous Attempts**: So far I have created a low level mouse hook that blocks mouse input to some target processes; however, the process I am interested in is not affected. I believe this is because the process uses Raw Input instead of usual windows messages.

**Question**: *How can I swallow these Raw Input mouse messages?*